# Imprimir objeto en java

Tags: java

Tengo un método de Java que agrega peliculas desde un archivo CSV. Una vez que obtengo los datos de la pelicula los guardo en un objeto. El problema que en la consola de Netbeans solo aparece:

```
model.Peliculas@7e5df0bd
model.Peliculas@30e2c55e
model.Peliculas@188d0799
model.Peliculas@3514cd6d
model.Peliculas@245d0b6a
model.Peliculas@233e28a
model.Peliculas@72729c9a
model.Peliculas@619e581c
model.Peliculas@2dd4091e
model.Peliculas@306e999c
model.Peliculas@569e5547
model.Peliculas@4553a930
model.Peliculas@4842c47d
```

Éste es mi método para leer los archivos y guardarlos en un objeto:

```
public void leerArchivoCSVd(ActionEvent e) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
 // TODO code application logic here
    try {
        archivolector = new FileReader(String.valueOf(txtdatosd.getText()));
        BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(archivolector);
        while(buffer.ready()){
            if(!(linea = buffer.readLine()).equals("\000")){
                // System.out.println(linea);
                pelisD = linea.split(",");

                id= pelisD[0].toString();
                nombre = pelisD[1].toString();
                genero = pelisD[2].toString();
                anio = pelisD[3].toString();
                calif = pelisD[4].toString();
                Peliculas peli = new Peliculas(id, nombre, genero, anio, calif);
                System.out.println(peli.toString());
                list.agregarAlFinal(peli);
                lista.add(peli);
            }
        }



    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }
}
```

Aquí es donde muestro es objeto Pelicula:

```
System.out.println(peli.toString());
```

Solo se muestra esto en la consola:

```
model.Peliculas@7e5df0bd
model.Peliculas@30e2c55e
model.Peliculas@188d0799
model.Peliculas@3514cd6d
model.Peliculas@245d0b6a
model.Peliculas@233e28a
model.Peliculas@72729c9a
model.Peliculas@619e581c
model.Peliculas@2dd4091e
model.Peliculas@306e999c
model.Peliculas@569e5547
model.Peliculas@4553a930
model.Peliculas@4842c47d
```

Comment: De esa forma no puedes consultar los campos debes definir los metodos get para Películas lo que haces ahora es obtener la referencia del objeto para que puedas imprimir texto por ejemplo System.out.println(peli.getId().toString()); [Metodos get y set en java](https://www.discoduroderoer.es/metodos-get-y-set-en-java/)

Comment: Al final no te ayudo mi respuesta? traté de realizarla lo más completa posible. @Antonio

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Debes redefinir el metodo toString() de la clase Peliculas, por el nombre de los parametros en su constructor, el metodo toString() quedaria parecido a:

> @Override 
>   public String toString()
>   {
>       String mensaje = "ID:"+id+"\nNombre: "+nombre+"\nGenero: "+genero+"\nAnio:
>      "+anio+"\nCalificacion: "+calif; 
>       return mensaje;
>   }

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 3):

Estas tratando de imprimir la representacion del objeto:

```
System.out.println(peli.toString());
```

por esa razón obtienes este tipo de información:

> model.Peliculas@30e2c55e model.Peliculas@188d0799
>   model.Peliculas@3514cd6d model.Peliculas@245d0b6a
>   model.Peliculas@233e28a model.Peliculas@72729c9a
>   model.Peliculas@619e581c model.Peliculas@2dd4091e
>   model.Peliculas@306e999c model.Peliculas@569e5547
>   model.Peliculas@4553a930 model.Peliculas@4842c47d

Si deseas imprimir el valor de una propiedad en el objeto, para eso tu objeto debe tener `getter's` y `setter's`, de esta forma obtendrías el valor del nombre mediante un `get` que debes tener en la definición de tu objeto, ejemplo:

```
 System.out.println(peli.getNombre());
```

Esta sería la forma que tendría tu objeto:

```
public final class Peliculas {

    private String id;
    private String nombre;
    private String genero;
    private String anio;
    private String calif;


    public Peliculas(String id, String nombre, String genero, String anio, String calif){
        this.id = id;
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.genero = genero;
        this.anio = anio;
        this.calif = calif;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getGenero() {
        return genero;
    }

    public void setGenero(String genero) {
        this.genero = genero;
    }

    public String getAnio() {
        return anio;
    }

    public void setAnio(String anio) {
        this.anio = anio;
    }

    public String getCalif() {
        return calif;
    }

    public void setCalif(String calif) {
        this.calif = calif;
    }

    private Peliculas(String id, ) {

    }
```

}

---

#### Imprimir el valor de un objeto en java.

Si deseas obtener toda la información del objeto mediante el método `toString()`, puedes sobreescribir este método en tu objeto y agregar los valores que serán retornados al llamar este método:

```
@Override
public String toString(){

    return "Id: '" + this.id + "', Nombre: '" + this.nombre + "', Genero: '" + this.genero + "'" + "', Año: '" + this.anio + "'" + "', Calificación: '" + this.calif + "'";

}
```

ahora si podrías imprimir la información:

```
Peliculas peli = new Peliculas(id, nombre, genero, anio, calif);
System.out.println(peli.toString());
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!