# Arraylist lectura

Tags: java

Necesito resolver este ejercicio y me da un error al leer el arraylist, soy nuevo programando, así que porfavor no juzgueis y responderme como mejor podaís para que pueda entenderlo. Entiendo que lo que lee es la ubicación del objeto, pero yo quiero leer el objeto String, después de esto tendria que crear un mapa para guardar cada palabra como clave y añadirle la ubicación de la frase con un for. El problema del código es que me imprime las referencias y yo quiero que me imprima el contenido, los objetos los tengo en el mismo main y todo, tendria que crear métodos?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class ReferenciasCruzadas {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        sc.nextLine();
        String frases[] = new String[n];
        ArrayList<String[]>palabras = new ArrayList<>();
        Map<String[], Integer> palabraClave = new TreeMap<>();
        //pide las frases
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            frases[i]= sc.nextLine();
        }
        //separa las frases en palabras
        for (int i = 0; i < frases.length; i++) {
            palabras.add(frases[i].split(" "));
        }



        System.out.println(palabras);
    }

}
```

Comment: Estaría bien que pusieras el código en vez de poner capturas de imagen mas que nada para que podamos copiarlo y mirar donde esta el error. Te aconsejo que edites la pregunta y lo hagas así.

Comment: El código debe ir _como texto, con formato_. No todos pueden ver las imágenes (aparte tampoco se puede hacer _copypaste_ de tu código de esa manera). Además, ¿cuál es el error?

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Imprimir objeto en java](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/212679/imprimir-objeto-en-java)

Comment: Ya está, he puesto el código y el error viene explicado, pero lo repetiré, el error es que me imprime la ubicación del objeto cuando yo lo que quiero es que me imprima el string. Y no responde a mi pregunta lo de imprimir objetos porque en este ejercicio como puedes ver todo está dentro del main.

Comment: para que vayas viendo, que pensas que estas iterando aca? for (int i = 0; i < frases.length; i++)??? y despues, que esperas que haga esto? palabras.add(frases[i].split(" "));? y despues, que esperas que imprima aca? System.out.println(palabras);? palabras es un array.. si lo mandas a imprimir, va a imprimir que es un array, no el contenido.. si queres el contenido, tenes que iterar el contenido ;)

Comment: Espero ahí recorrer el array de frases e ir agregando las frases separadas por espacios al arraylist, también he probado recorriendo el arraylist con elnombredearraylist.size() si es a lo que te refieres con iterar

Comment: por lo que entendi es que quieres que muestre las palabras almacenadas en el arraylist, tu salida estaria mal, porque tu estas diciendo que te muestre palabra y esa es una direccion de memoria que almacena mas direcciones, velo como una lista simple enlazada, para recuperar la palabra y no la direccion de memoria debes usar get()

Answer (score 0):

1 podes usar `Array.toString()` para imprimir el objeto obtenido en cada iteracion importando la clase Arrays

```
import java.util.Arrays;

    for (String[]palabra:palabras) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(palabra));
         }
```

tambien podes iterar el arraylist y luego los arrays guardados,se usa `size()` para obtener el tamaño del arraylist y `get()` para obtener los valores guardados individualmente

```
  for (int i=0;i<palabras.size();i++ ) {
            for (int j=0;j<palabras.get(i).length;j++ ) {
                System.out.println(palabras.get(i)[j]);
            }
         }
```

o usar expresion lambda

```
 palabras.forEach((p) -> Arrays.stream(p).forEach(o ->System.out.println(o)));
```

Comment: no me vale, porque para empezar no es una matriz es un arraylist del cual quiero devolver cada string. y tampoco me vale con get me sigue devolviendo de todas las maneras la posición

Comment: Un doble ciclo for no esta condicionado solo a imprimir matriz  , tus datos estan guardados en un Arraylist y para acceder a esos datos  debes iterar el Arraylist 1er for y luego iterar el Array obtenido 2do for

Comment: explicámelo poniendo los for, porque no entiendo que iteres con dos for cuando el único método para acceder a arraylist es .get() donde pondría las variables de los for?

Comment: en el 1er for con get obtienes un array el cual fue generado por split() con el 2do for obtines los valores String guardados en ese array [ejecucion](https://onlinegdb.com/7vePOi6FQw)

Comment: Y ya puestos a usar lambdas, también se pueden usar method references: `palabras.stream().flatMap(Arrays::stream).forEach(System.out::println);`

Answer (score 0):

Te diré que tu código no parece que tenga sentido. Pero te dejo aquí una solución a tu problema. Luego puedes mejorarlo a partir de ella con lo que tú quieras...

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class ReferenciasCruzadas {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        sc.nextLine();
        String frases[] = new String[n];
        ArrayList<String[]>palabras = new ArrayList<>();
        Map<String[], Integer> palabraClave = new TreeMap<>();
        //pide las frases
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            frases[i]= sc.nextLine();
        }
        //separa las frases en palabras
        for (int i = 0; i < frases.length; i++) {
            palabras.add(frases[i].split(" "));
            String[] palabra = palabras.get(i);
            System.out.println(palabra[0]);
        }

        sc.close();

        
    }

}
```