# ¿Cómo puedo imprimir este arreglo?

Tags: java, array, validación, ordenamiento

Tengo que desarrollar un programa que mediante arreglos, permita ordenar utilizando el metodo de burbuja artículos por su monto de inversión.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Articulos listaArticulos[] = new Articulos[3];

        listaArticulos[0] = new Articulos("Azucar", 4, 4);
        listaArticulos[1] = new Articulos("Atun", 3, 3);
        listaArticulos[2] = new Articulos("Leche", 2, 2);

        for (int i = 0; i <listaArticulos.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(listaArticulos[i]);

        }
    }

}
```

Por ahora llevo esto, el problema es que cuando lo imprimo, sale de esta manera:

```
Articulos@2133c8f8
Articulos@43a25848
Articulos@3ac3fd8b
```

```
public class Articulos {

    private String nombre;
    private int precio;
    private int cantidad;


    public Articulos(String nombre, int precio, int cantidad) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.precio = precio;
        this.cantidad = cantidad;

    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public int getPrecio() {
        return precio;
    }

    public void setPrecio(int precio) {
        this.precio = precio;
    }

    public int getCantidad() {
        return cantidad;
    }

    public void setCantidad(int cantidad) {
        this.cantidad = cantidad;
    }
 }
```

Aún debo agregar el valor de la inversión y no sé si es posible multiplicar los datos del precio y cantidad que están en el arreglo para agregar un cuarto dato que sería el de inversión y de ahí con el método de la burbuja acomodar los artículos de manera ascendente dependiendo de el valor de la inversión. ¿Se tiene que acomodar en otro nuevo arreglo todos los datos junto con la inversión?

Comment: Obviamente, cuando imprimes un objeto lo que java te pone en pantalla es su dirección en memoria así como la clase a la que pertenece, pero nada "útil" para "ver" el objeto. Hay dos posibilidades, 1) en tu loop imprimes directamente lo que quieres -> `System.out.println(listaArticulos[i].getNombre() + listaArticulos[i].getCantidad()...)` o 2) en tu clase Articulos añades el método `public String toString() { return this.nombre + " " + this.cantidad + " " + this.precio; }` (por ejemplo), y *automágicamente* Java invocará este método, imprimiendo algo más legible para cada objeto.

Comment: hola, muchas gracias

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Imprimir objeto en java](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/212679/imprimir-objeto-en-java)

Answer (score 1):

Estas intentando mostrar objetos Articulos. Para mostrar la información de estos objetos prueba a implementar el método toString o dentro del bucle for muestra los datos por separado con sus respectivos getter.
Solucion con toString:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Articulos [nombre=" + nombre + ", precio=" + precio + ", cantidad=" + cantidad + "]";
}
```

Clase main:

```
for (int i = 0; i <listaArticulos.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(listaArticulos[i].toString());

}
```

Solución con getters:

```
for (int i = 0; i <listaArticulos.length; i++) {
    Articulos articulos=listaArticulos[i];
    System.out.println("Nombre: "+articulos.getNombre()+" Precio: "+articulos.getPrecio()+" Cantidad: "+articulos.getCantidad());
    

}
```